# Is there a way to automate data cleaning for pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am cleaning my data for a machine learning project by replacing the missing values with the zeros and the mean for the 'Age' and 'Fare' columns respectively. The code for which is given below:

```
train_data['Age'] = train_data['Age'].fillna(0) 
mean = train_data['Fare'].mean()    
train_data['Fare'] = train_data['Fare'].fillna(mean)
```

Since I would I have to do this multiple times for other sets of data, I want to automate this process by creating a generic function that takes the DataFrame as input and performs the operations for modifying it and returning the modified function. The code for that is given below:

```
def data_cleaning(df):
    df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(0)
    fare_mean = df['Fare'].mean()
    df['Fare'] = df['Fare'].fillna()
    return df
```

However when I pass the training data DataFrame:

```
train_data = data_cleaning(train_data)
```

I get the following error:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: 
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-  
docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_42/1440633985.py in <module>
      1 #print(train_data)
----> 2 train_data = data_cleaning(train_data)
      3 cross_val_data = data_cleaning(cross_val_data)

/tmp/ipykernel_42/3053068338.py in data_cleaning(df)
      2     df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(0)
      3     fare_mean = df['Fare'].mean()
----> 4     df['Fare'] = df['Fare'].fillna()
      5     return df

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, 
**kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in fillna(self, value, 
method, axis, inplace, limit, downcast)
   4820             inplace=inplace,
   4821             limit=limit,
-> 4822             downcast=downcast,
   4823         )
   4824 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in fillna(self, value, 
method, axis, inplace, limit, downcast)
   6311         """
   6312         inplace = validate_bool_kwarg(inplace, "inplace")
-> 6313         value, method = validate_fillna_kwargs(value, method)
   6314 
   6315         self._consolidate_inplace()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_validators.py in 
validate_fillna_kwargs(value, method, validate_scalar_dict_value)
        368 
        369     if value is None and method is None:
    --> 370         raise ValueError("Must specify a fill 'value' or 'method'.")
        371     elif value is None and method is not None:
        372         method = clean_fill_method(method)

    ValueError: Must specify a fill 'value' or 'method'.
```

On some research, I found that I would have to use apply() and map() functions instead, but I am not sure how to input the mean value of the column. Furthermore, this does not scale well as I would have to calculate all the fillna values before inputting them into the function, which is cumbersome. Therefore I want to ask, is there better way to automate data cleaning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

This line `df['Fare'] = df['Fare'].fillna()` in your function, you did not fill the n/a with anything, thus it returns an error. You should change it to `df['Fare'] = df['Fare'].fillna(fare_mean)`.

If you intend to make this usable for another file in same directory, you can just call it in another file by:

```
from file_that_contain_function import function_name
```

And if you intend to make it reusable for your workspace/virtual environment, you may need to create your own python package.

Comment: It's shown in the error message you put in the question, are you sure that it wasn't the problem/error?

Comment: sorry, I hadn't noticed it

Comment: However, I still get the warning

Comment: Can you please show tell the warning?

Comment: Its the same warning that is shown in the first part of the error message

Comment: /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: You can simply ignore that or set the warning off https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: I recommend *not* ignoring/turning off warnings.  Warnings are there for a reason...

Answer (score 0):

So yes, the other answer explains where the *error* is coming from.

However, the *warning* at the beginning has nothing to do with filling NaNs. The warning is telling you that you are modifying a slice of a copy of your dataframe. Change your code to

```py
def data_cleaning(df):
    df['Age'] = df.loc[:, 'Age'].fillna(0)
    fare_mean = df['Fare'].mean()
    df['Fare'] = df.loc[:, 'Fare'].fillna(fare_mean)  # <- and also fix this error
    return df
```

I suggest also searching that specific warning here, as there are hundreds of posts detailing this warning and how to deal with it. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) a good one.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, however, I'm still getting the warning:   
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: However, I have got some understanding of the issue, and will try to resolve it.